# Spacy annotation error [E152] The attribute ORTHO is not supported for token patterns

Tags: entity, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Am having this error when I tried annotating the entities using spacy patterns

Eg:- patterns = [

{'label' : 'SKILL', pattern: [{'LOWER': 'tensorflow'},{'ORTHO' : '-'},{'LIKE_NUM': True}]}

Error:- [E152] The attribute ORTHO is not supported for token patterns

I tried running the above pattern but was stuck with Error [E152]